# Studio ImageView Error Force Close

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

Any one know how to fix this error? The activity won't open and the app force close once I open the project that has the codes my XML has viewflipper with plenty of photo so I think its too many for the app to handle?

```
 03-05 03:34:03.409 6563-6563/org.intercode.lifeatceu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:126)
         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:846)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
         at org.intercode.lifeatceu.PFOT.onCreate(PFOT.java:28)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

PFOT.java line 28 is

```
setContentView(R.layout.pfot);
```

Comment: but all images i put is like 50-300kb and it works fine with other activity...

Answer (score 0):

It's an Out of Memory error, you have a very large image in your resources that you are trying to display and is exceeding the maximum size. Check your XML layouts for drawables and downsize any large ones.

Comment: what i put in drawables are all 50-300kb and other project work with that idk -.-

Comment: It's not a matter of the size in KB, it's the size in pixels. Your images on disk are most likely compressed, but to be displayed they need to be converted to a bitmap, which is much larger.

Comment: its 700x400... what would be a better size for it tho?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're consuming way too much memory for your process, which is resulting in the allocation failing, after its nearing filled. You should consider looking at the images and how you're loading and how you're impacting memory over time.

Comment: but what i try to load oncreate is only like 50-300kb image doesnt work on this activity but works on other activity

Comment: you need to look at the memory of your application activities over time.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use Vectore Drawable  instead of png ans jpj file

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

(2) Add this line  to build.gradal file

defaultConfig {

```
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

(3) In your xml file add this line in parent layout

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

(4) Use srcCompat attribute in the ImageView like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/sf_tick"
                tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```